# Get the width/height of paper using JointJS

Tags: jointjs

I resize the paper size by moving model :

```
paper.on('cell:pointermove', 
function(cellView, evt, x, y) { 
    if((x+cellView.model.prop('size/width'))>=650 &&(y+cellView.model.prop('size/height'))>=200)
    paper.setDimensions(x+cellView.model.prop('size/width'), y+cellView.model.prop('size/height'));
}
```

Is there any way I can change the property of paper just like `element.prop(properties)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the `width`/`height` of the paper with `paper.options.width` and `paper.options.height`. Paper is a view, not a model so it does not have `set()`/`get()`/`prop()`/`attr()` methods but you can always store properties to it just like to any other object if you want: `paper.foo = 'bar'`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just call `paper.fitToContent()`?

Comment: Please either turn this into a clarificatin comment ( you do have the commenting privilege) or into a more assertive answer. As it currently is, this could be considered "not an answer".